# ffmpeg getting error "Failed to seek for auxiliary info, will only parse senc atoms for encryption"

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i link.mpd -c copy file.mp4
```

But getting error:

> Failed to seek for auxiliary info, will only parse senc atoms for
> encryption info

Please help me. What can I do to fix it?